# How to send log to efk server

Tags: php, efk

I'm developing a new micro-service with **php language**, and I want that the logging will be sent to **efk** server.

What logging Framework should I use in my php app?

How can I sent just the app log (no the whole syslog or apache server log)?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Monolog](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog). It's versatile, is used by some of the big frameworks, and has support for `PSR-3`. It's extensible and also supports logging to multiple channels (`stderr`, logfiles, Loggly, etc)

Once installed & configured, you can use it like so:

```
// Create the logger
$logger = new Logger('my_logger');

/**
* Now add a handler to log to a local file (you could configure a remote logging service
* or DB connection, or anything you've created to extend monolog)
*/
$logger->pushHandler(new StreamHandler(__DIR__.'/my_app.log', Logger::DEBUG));

// You can now use your logger
$logger->info('Some interesting thing happened in my app');
```